# 6 piece mystery puzzle help!

Tags: geometry, three-dimensional

[image]

So I have NO CLUE how to put this back together. I don't even remember what it looks like or what it's even called. I took it apart 3 years ago and it's still driving me crazy. Anyone have any ideas?!?!?!

Comment: Can you confirm the dimension of those six parts is 6x6x1? No third dimension involved? (i.e. they would all fit in a 6x6x6 cube)

Comment: Oops, I meant six 5x5x1 pieces

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is the Squarrel puzzle, invented by Ronald Kint-Bruynseels.  You can find a description at Ishino's website, http://puzzlewillbeplayed.com/6BoardBurr/Squarrel/.  It looks like there's a solution video at https://youtu.be/GxMKdVrhxow.  There is also Andreas Rover's excellent BurrTools software that can solve puzzles like this if there are no rotational movements.